# Trouble Passing dynamic entries using variable

Tags: javascript

The below JavaScript code displays line chart using chart.js. The code works fine however, if you look at the part of the code  near labels I am trying to pass it dynamically using a variable instead of having a static list of months. For example I just want to pass from Jan - May.

I am using a variable x to do that but it would not work as a separate labels it would display as one label example in the image. Is there a way i can pass those label dynamically ? I don't want to use separate variables since my list will be based on n.

[image]

Original

```
var lineChartData = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(54,61,251,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(54,61,251,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(54,61,251,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(54,61,251,1)",
                    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
                }
```

Modified Version

```
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

        var x = ' \"January\" , \"February\" ';
        var lineChartData = {
            labels : [x,"March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(54,61,251,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(54,61,251,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(54,61,251,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(54,61,251,1)",
                    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
                }
            ]

        }

    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
    }
```

Comment: The problem is you made `' \"January\" , \"February\" ';` a single string literal.

Comment: `var x = ["Jan","Feb"..."May"]` and `labels : x,` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to declare `x` (currently declared as a string) as an array instead. The, you join the two arrays together using `.concat` so that your `labels` property has the full list:

```
    var x = ["January", "February"];
    var lineChartData = {
        labels : x.concat(["March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]),
```